# Is there a way to filter in Trello to only show uncompleted Checklist items?

Tags: trello

I'm wondering if there's a way to filter in Trello to only show uncompleted Checklist items or the Cards containing them.

Is there?

Answer (score 4):

There is not currently a way to filter cards that way, no.

Comment: Bummer. I'm going to suggest that this be added as a feature.Thanks!